# Heat service on Openstack doesn't work when launch command "openstack orchestration service list"

Tags: openstack, heat, orchestration

I installed Heat service for Openstack Stein on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS host following this link:

https://docs.openstack.org/heat/stein/install/install-ubuntu.html

but when i verify installation using this link:

https://docs.openstack.org/heat/stein/install/verify.html

I get the following result:

```
controller@controller:~$ openstack orchestration service list
WARNING: Failed to import plugin clustering.
ERROR: None
```

How I can solve it? Thanks in advance.